# How to filter Wordpress gallery captions?

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to filter my wordpress galleries caption text. When an image caption is empty, I would like to add the post title + $i. The output code should be:

```
<dl>
  <dt>
    <a><img src="http://example.com"></a>
  </dt>
  <dd>
    POST TITLE 1
  </dd>
</dl>
```

I have been looking for a wp_get_attachment_metadata filter but I couldn't find a solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Check the doc for **wp generate attachment metadata** and **attachment fields to save**. I think you should be able to access the fields and add your caption there.

Comment: Unfortunately we don't pass through the `img_caption_shortcode` filter when the caption text is originally empty...

Answer (score 0):

The [Gallery Image Captions (GIC)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gallery-image-captions/) plugin adds a much-needed hook to the WordPress `media.php` file. Using GIC as an example, you can write a filter to handle empty image captions.

```
// This will display a default caption for attachments with empty captions.
function my_default_gallery_image_caption($attachment_id, $captiontag, $selector, $itemtag) {

    $id = $attachment_id;

    $my_image_meta = galimgcaps_get_image_meta($id);

    $caption_string = ( !empty( $my_image_meta['caption'] ) ) ? $my_image_meta['caption'] : 'YOUR CUSTOM CAPTION GOES HERE';

     return "<{$captiontag} class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption' id='{$selector}-{$id}'>" . $caption_string . "</{$captiontag}></{$itemtag}>";
}
add_filter('galimgcaps_gallery_image_caption', 'my_default_gallery_image_caption', 10, 4);
```

**Screen Grab**

[image]

I hope that helps. Holler if you have any questions :-)